# How can I create two separately configured bootRun tasks using Gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I want to define two different versions of the `bootRun` task in a Spring boot application using Gradle. This is my attempt, which worked for customizing a single `bootRun` task. But with multiple tasks containing `bootRun`, the last `bootRun` overrides the previous ones.

```
task local {
  bootRun {
    systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", "dev,postgres"
    jvmArgs "--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
  }
}
local.finalizedBy bootRun

task prod {
  bootRun {
    systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", "postgres"
    jvmArgs "--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED"
  }
}
prod.finalizedBy bootRun
```

Here, when I run `./gradlew :local`, the spring profiles are only `postgres`. When I comment out the `prod` task, I get both `dev,postgres` as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As currently written, your `local` and `prod` tasks are default tasks that aren't really doing anything. Your use of `bootRun` within their configuration is altering the configuration of the existing `bootRun` task that Spring Boot's Gradle plugin defines.

When you define the tasks, you need to tell Gradle that they are a `BootRun` task:

```
task local(type: org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun) {
    // …
}
```

You also need to configure the main class name and the classpath of your new task. You probably want those to be the same as the default `bootRun` task:

```
task local(type: org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun) {
    mainClass = bootRun.mainClass
    classpath = bootRun.classpath
}
```

You can then customize the system properties and JVM arguments as you were before. Putting this all together, you can configure your `local` and `prod` tasks like this:

```
task local(type: org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun) {
    mainClass = bootRun.mainClass
    classpath = bootRun.classpath
    systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", "dev,postgres"
    jvmArgs "--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
}

task prod(type: org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun) {
    mainClass = bootRun.mainClass
    classpath = bootRun.classpath
    systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", "postgres"
    jvmArgs "--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED"
}
```